# Mock Celery Task method apply_async

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, celery

I create one celery task which has dependency on other module. I delayed celery task at model save method and i want to pass all test cases without celery. Below is my code.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):

        super(Offers, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None)

        change_offer_status.apply_async(args=[self.id], eta=self.valid_to, queue='credr_core_task',
                                               routing_key='credr_core_task')
```

Test.py

```
class OfferTests(APITestCase):
    authenticated_client = APIClient()

    def setUp(self):
        data = {
            "username": "vivek",
            "first_name": "Vivek",
            "last_name": "Dogra",
            "email": "vivk@credr.com",
            "contact_number": "9834982602",
            "password": "easy"
        }
        self.user = User.objects.create(data)
        token = Token.objects.get(user__username='vivek')
        self.authenticated_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
        mock_task = Mock()
        mock_task.get = Mock(return_value={'success': True})

        print mock_task.get() # outputs {'success': True}

        with patch('offers.tasks.change_offer_status.apply_async', new=mock_task) as mocked_task:
            mocked_task.return_value = True

    @override_settings(CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS=True,
                   CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True, )
    def test_add_offer(self):
        """
        add user address
        """
        start_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        end_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=3), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        data = {
            "type": OfferTypeEnum.FLAT._value_,
            "name": "CredR Offer",
            "code": "FLAT100",
            "status": OfferStatusEnum.ACTIVE._value_,
            "value": "1004",
            "discount_value": 1004,
            "valid_from": start_date,
            "valid_to": end_date,
            "message": "GET FLAT 100"
        }
        response = self.authenticated_client.post(URL, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I have created one mock object in setUp method. But i get connection refused error of rabbitMq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to pass all test cases without celery

Set `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` when running your tests.

> [...] tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the queue.

It may pay to read through the other configuration options here too: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager

Comment: Still not working...i updated my question...please check and let me know where i am making mistake..

Comment: This is True, apply async does not make the task trigger immediately unfortunately

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

From your words "...i want to pass all test cases without celery." and "...But i get connection refused error of rabbitMq", **I guess you are trying to run the tests without triggering REAL celery tasks**.

If that's true, you do not want to mock `apply_async`. The real requirement is to prevent celery sending messages to queue to trigger the task. So you may want to mock **`send_task`** of you celery app.

Says you have `celeryapp` instance in `offer` module. You may try to use 
**`patch('offers.celeryapp.send_task', new=mock_task)`**

to replace

`patch('offers.tasks.change_offer_status.apply_async', new=mock_task)`.

Then your celery app should not send message.

And if you are using Celery 4+ (I forgot detail version), `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` need to be changed to `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER`