# How to mock the celery apply_async to instead use .s().apply()

Tags: pytest, patch, monkeypatching

I have a function, which indirectly calls a celery task using apply_async() internally.

```
def abc(...):
   send_notification.apply_async(...)
```

where send_notification is a celery task method:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def send_notification(self, ...):
    ...
```

Now, I'm writing a test case for testing `abc()`, where I'd want to convert invocation of `send_notification.apply_async()` to `send_notification.s(...).apply()`.

Is this something thats possible using mock/monkeypatch/patch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock Celery Task method apply\_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284043/mock-celery-task-method-apply-async)